# How to solve Unexpected character '�' (1:0) error

Tags: jsx, visual-studio-code

When I create jsx files in the terminal with the echo command, these files show character errors although I have no errors in the first line.

Error:
[image]

Comment: You might have the wrong encoding in your terminal session, try `$ locale` as command in your terminal, and check that the encoding is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: When we create jsx files in the terminal with the echo command, these files convert to UTF-16, which creates a character that cannot be compiled. It returns us as a character error.It is necessary to set the solution to vscode (Visual Studio Code) as UTF-8.

[solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjUgf.png)